# In vscode, how to define a shortcut to invoke a custom snippet for current active language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, code-snippets

Let's say I have a `Ruby` user snippet to output the string **ruby** and a `Python` user snippet to output the string **python**. How can I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to invoke the aforementioned `Ruby` snippet when in ruby-mode, and invoke the `Python` snippet when in python-mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "ruby"
    },
    "when": "editorLangId == ruby"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "python"
    },
    "when": "editorLangId == python"
},
```

Also, instead of using the snippet argument value to define your snippet inline, you can reference an existing snippet by using the `langId` and `name` arguments.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers#_known-language-identifiers

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_assign-keybindings-to-snippets

Comment: Thanks Alex for pointing me the right direction. In your example, the `"snippet": "ruby"` is an inline snippet. I've changed it to `"name": "my_snippet_name"` to reference my already defined snippet and it works as expected.